# Typing a dynamic function that merges dictionaries resulting from function calls

Tags: typescript

I've been scratching my head around this for a while. I can implement this in a couple of ways, but I can't arrive at an implementation with proper typing.

So, here's what I want to do. Behold my "compile" function, which should compile an obj after a series of function calls.

```js
const obj = compile(
    {a: 1}, 
    (obj) => ({b:"lorem"}), // f1
    (obj) => ({c: obj.a * 10}), // f2
)

> {a:1, b:"lorem", c:10}
```

We call the function by passing a default object and a **variable number** of functions. It executes each function with the previous result (see below), merges the result with the past result and passes it to the next function.

This is confusing, so here's the explanation of the above call.

- We pass in a default obj: `{a:1}`. This is the starting point.
- That obj is passed to `f1` which returns `{b:2}`. We join the 2 resulting in `{a:1, b:"lorem"}`
- We pass the previous result `{a:1, b:"lorem"}` to `f2`. `f2` returns `{c: 10}`, which we merge with the previous result, ending up with `{a:1, b:"lorem", c:10}`.
- Since we do not have any more functions, we use the previous result as the final result of the function.

**Type of result should guessable by typescript as `{a: number, b: string, c: number}`**

Comment: So you want to merge x amount of objects into an object, but restrict the 1st added object key to string type(you said guessable, so the language should know)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to give that a call signature that works flawlessly for arbitrarily many arguments (you will find that the contextual inference of `obj` in your callbacks will fail, even if the rest of the generic inference succeeds).  You can pick an arbitrary fixed number of arguments to support (say, 20) and generate a call signature for it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVk2Mm).  Does that approach meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing? (If you reply please mention @jcalz so I am notified)